# Signing failure after editing jar file

Tags: java, jar, jnlp

I did some String changes to a "*.properties" file inside a JAR file.
I tried to open application after the change, but I get the following signing error:
"could not verify signing in resource: ... XXX.jar".

I'm new at Java, Is there any way to edit JNLP file and pass the error?

Answer (score 0):

you can't edit jar file.
you can edit the java project inside eclipse and after regenerate jar file.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have the java project, only the JAR.

Comment: That is why signing process is for, @shloro.

Comment: @shloro you can import jar file in eclipse, File -> Import -> General -> Archive File